# Does Evolution+OpenSync have Calendar+Contacts+Notes and cloudless sync with iPhone+Android?

Tags: wireless, android, sync, evolution, iphone

I've been a solid Windows laptop person since I bought my first computer 2 decades ago.  I would like to move to Ubuntu, since Windows is getting slower and slower despite laptops getting more powerful.  I've always relied on Cygwin to navigate my laptops, so I'm partway to being a Linux user.  When I replaced my laptop in 2019, I further weaned myself off of Windows a little bit by going with LibreOffice instead of Office.

The only problem is my reliance on Outlook as my personal information manager (PIM).  So in 2019, I also bought Outlook 2019 at well over $100 local currency.  It was *way* slower and less reliable than the many-versions older Outlook that I used on Windows 7.  And yet my reliance on Outlook was the only reason why I went with Windows 10 instead of switching to Linux.  After a few years, I'm at a point where I am more serious about switching, but I'm not getting a warm fuzzy feeling about the PIM alternatives.

From what I could find online, Ubuntu uses Evolution for the PIM.  And it syncs with devices using OpenSync.  The only Wikipedia page for OpenSync is in [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSync), which I don't understand, though Google Translate does a good job of translating. The current version of OpenSync is 2009.  Most of the information I can find online is in the order of a decade or more old, mentioning devices like Palm Pilot or [Palm](https://www.linuxlinks.com/Evolution/) devices.  I don't see mention of Android or iPhone.  Inforation on YouTube dated [2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPtUjQZZ1jE) says that it is a dormant system.

**Is Evolution and OpenSync kept up-to-date, with basic PIM functionality and interoperability with native PIM apps on Android and iPhone?**  How realistic is it for a non-developer to set up?

I currently use iPhone, but I actually like Android functionality too.  I just trust Apple more (or mistrust it less), and I rely a lot on its built-in PIM functionality.  I'm a big believer and minimizing reliance on 3rd party apps in order to avoid being asked for all sorts of permissions that they shouldn't need.  The only PIM functionality I need is Calendar, Contacts, and text Notes.  On the phone, I don't care about having an email client as I rely on browser access to Gmail.  [This page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) doesn't mention Notes, and I'm hoping that this doesn't necessarily mean that it lacks a Notes-like function.

I also eschew the cloud for PIM.  I liberally store pass codes and such in my Contacts.  I only use local WiFi to sync PIM data between the phone and laptop.  This is enabled by AkrutoSync on Windows, which accesses Outlook's PIM data an presents a Exchange interface to the iPhone.  Unfortunately, AkrutoSync is not available on Linux.  So part of what I consider to be up-to-date PIM functionality on Ubuntu is to be able to cloudlessly sync to an iPhone or Android.

*If Evolution+OpenSync won't meet my needs can veteran Ubuntu users suggest what might?*

Comment: You may be interested in [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/). It will do what you’re asking and a bunch more, and has native applications for every major OS (including Ubuntu, of course, which has deeper integrations). The learning curve to set it up may be a bit steep depending on your existing skill set, but it’s a solid option 

Comment: @matigo: I've browsed the site and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nextcloud).  It seems quite overwhelming for my needs and area of expertise (not development or IT/IM).  Thanks anyway.